# SimpleDateFormat does not work on some android versions

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I have to read dates in following format **Sat, 19 Jan 2013 00:00:00 +0100**.
My formatter is

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
```

When I want to set data :

```
try {
    myObject.setEndDate(format.parse(currentValue));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This works perfect if I use it in simple java project or on my *Nexus* and *Htc* but when I attach to debugger a *Samsung s3* it gives parser exception .

I want this to work on all versions of android and phones.

Comment: And the stack trace of the exception is? Don't you think the exception message could be helpful in diagnosing what the problem is?

Comment: it is souranded with try catch when I inspect e it says just parser error (just when s3 is connected , on nexus and emulator works perfect )

Comment: You're printing the stack trace. So, what is printed? Paste the complete and exact stack trace.

Comment: when I inspect e I have java.text.ParserExeption but it does not pront any stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by computing date without simple date format in try catch 
When running on some phones it does not gets in catch and format works well and running on other phones it gets in catch but date is computed well .

```
   if(localName.equals("startDate") && currentValue!=null){

    try {
        myObject.setStartDate(format.parse(currentValue));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        String  dates [] = currentValue.split(" ");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(dates[1]));
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(dates[3]));
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, StaticDataUtils.months.get(dates[2]));
        String hours [] = dates[4].split(":");
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hours[0]));
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(hours[1]));
        myObject.setStartDate(cal.getTime());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Try this:

Comment: Sat, 19 Jan 2013 00:00:00 +0100  Like this looks my date so I don t have to put . after s . What means SSSZ?

Comment: @RalucaGurau You still getting exception?

Comment: yes when I inspect e I have java.text.ParserExeption but it does not pront any stack

Answer (score 0):

In the catch print the `currentValue`, and `Locale.getDefaultLocale()` too. Most likely the locale prevents parsing of the currentValue.

At least then you might try the code on a PC with exact same parameters.